# Sharpe ratios (and other risk-adjusted metrics) on Terminal wealth (long-horizon payoffs)

Tags: sharpe-ratio, compounding, payoff, bootstrap

I'm exploring financial simulations with bootstrapped returns (TxNBoot) to calculate long-horizon returns. Terminal wealth (e.g compounded returns at T) is a vector of payoffs (NBootx1), typically following a log-normal distribution with minimum values above 0 due to compounding.

**Can I calculate the Sharpe ratio on these payoffs (with the cross-sectional mean and standard deviation at T)?**

While this seems feasible, I'm encountering challenges when applying other risk-adjusted metrics like the Sortino ratio and Omega ratio, which are traditionally used with the time-series of returns rather than payoffs.

Any insights on this and potential alternatives for assessing risk-adjusted performance of these payoffs would be appreciated.  At the end maximizing compound rates and, hence, terminal wealth is what matters to most investors, no?

#### Refs

Cochrane, J.H., 2022. Portfolios for long-term investors. Review of Finance, 26(1), pp.1-42.

Kazemi, H., Schneeweis, T. and Gupta, B., 2004. Omega as a performance measure. JOURNAL OF PERFORMANCE MEASUREMENT., 8, pp.16-25.

Sharpe, W.F., 1998. The sharpe ratio. Streetwise–the Best of the Journal of Portfolio Management, 3, pp.169-85.